# How to trigger window periodically?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'd like to process the last N-hour data on every M-minutes. Data comes through pubsub with various delays, but I don't want to delay window triggering due to time skew or data lag. That is, I just want to process the data available at the time of triggering and want to trigger based on wall time (but each window should include data between [Triggered time - M hours, Triggered time) based on data event time.)

I'm trying to use SlidingWindows, but the triggering is based on the event time and seems to be delayed due to data lag.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(...)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/AfterProcessingTime.java) trigger with FixedWindows.  This will behave exactly as you describe.